# how to get rid of -std=c++17 in g++ command line?

Tags: c++

I have encountered an error, saying that std::size() is not a member of std. Then I found this link: [Why std::size() is not a member of std in gcc 8.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55194309/why-stdsize-is-not-a-member-of-std-in-gcc-8-2-0) Eventually, my code works well after I compile the file with `g++ -std=c++17 myFile.cpp`. Now, I tried `g++ -std=c++17 6.cpp -o - 6.out` as the previous link suggested, and it did not work. Any comments?

Comment: I'm quite confused by your question. It seems you have already learned that `std::size` is a C++17 feature, and this is not enabled by default in `g++`, right? Then your title seems to suggest you don't want to have to explicitly enable this every time, but your question seems to be about a misunderstanding on how to specify the output file name? Please try to clarify what you are asking. It will help to explain exactly what you are hoping for, and what happens instead, including any error messages.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++17 6.cpp -o - 6.out` looks like it has an extra `-` (dash) between `-o` and filename.

Comment: I edited that answer, should be working now.

Comment: g++ -std=c++17 6.cpp -o 6.out
g++: error: 6.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: @BoBTFish, I thought using g++ -std=c++17 6.cpp -o - 6.out could get rid of the -std=c++17 in g++ command line.

Comment: @kkxx Maybe your "6.cpp" does not exist at the location where you call `g++`

Comment: You shouldn't just copy and paste commands from the Internet (even from Stack Overflow) to your computer *without any understanding what they are doing*. You have a working command `g++ -std=c++17 myFile.cpp`. Now read up on what `-o` is doing and what should follow it and only then add it to your build command.

Comment: And no, nothing can get rid of `-std=c++17` in your build command. The only possibility would be to upgrade the compiler version, but such version *doesn't exist yet*. Newest `gcc` version uses C++14 by default. If you want to use C++17 features, you have to tell that to your compiler.

Comment: @kkxx The command works but you made a typo. As @Yksisarvinen told you, you have an extra `-` character between `-o` and `6.out`. Just remove this extra dash and it will work as expected.

Comment: The amount of flags your compiler needs to function properly shouldn't concern you, since you shouldn't invoke it manually most of the time. Consider using a makefile (or some other build system).

Comment: If you are using the bash shell, `alias g++17='g++ -std=c++17'` might be useful for your situation.

Answer (score 7):

Compile with the following command:

```
g++ -std=c++17 yourFile.cpp -o output_executable_name
```

Replace `yourFile.cpp` by the name of your `.cpp` file, and `output_executable_name` by the name you want, it will generate an executable with this name.

Find [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++) more information on g++ compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a shell alias.

If you really want to get rid of having to type `-std=c++17` you can set an alias in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file (or whatever rc file corresponding to the shell you use).

I mainly use zsh but it's the same process for almost all shells...

Find out which shell your using with `echo $SHELL` this will likely either be `/bin/zsh` or `/bin/bash`. then proceed with the following depending on your shell

`vim ~/.zshrc` or `vim ~/.bashrc` (depending on your shell)

add `alias g++="g++ -std=c++17"` then save the file

restart your current shell/terminal window (close and reopen)

next time you go to compile with:

`g++ ...` the shell will replace it with `g++ -std=c++17` and saved yourself 10 keystrokes.

Note: This isn't advised if you're going to be working with various compliler versions for different projects down the road but if you're asking this question it likely will never matter. glhf!